# Socket IO working example in Java

Tags: java, sockets, socket.io

Is there a working example of a Server and a Client which is using Socket IO protocol. and it needs to be in Java.

I was going through netty server and implemented a server client pair. But the code seems to not work.

Any help is welcomed.

Thank you

Comment: 'Socket IO' isn't a protocol. It's an API that unites several protocols.

Comment: Sorry about that mistake

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-networking/sockets.html